# StructureMap to Ninject rules

Tags: structuremap, ninject

How to write this StructureMap line in Ninject

```
        ForRequestedType<HttpContextBase>()
            .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(x => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Bind<HttpContextBase>().ToMethod(context => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

Comment: Delegate 'System.Func<Ninject.Activation.IContext,System.Web.HttpContextBase>' does not take 0 arguments

Comment: Ah, oops. I had used a lambda with zero arguments. Thanks for the edit Ruben.